# how can to use Persian Calander in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-datepicker

i using a specific date library(https://github.com/mohamad-amin/PersianMaterialDateTimePicker)

now i want using it in a button in Recycler View.

now my problem is I have to define two options in library codes :

1 - I should refer to the activity.

2 - i need to use getSupport FragmentManager().

but this page has been extends with Recycler View.Adapter and I do not know how to call these two options on this page.

RecyclerViewAdapter page :

```
                        PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();

                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance( StudentList.this ,
                            persianCalendar.getPersianYear() ,
                            persianCalendar.getPersianMonth() ,
                            persianCalendar.getPersianDay());




                    datePickerDialog.show( getSupportFragmentManager() , "datePickerDialog" );
```

In these pictures you can easily understand me :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbQGX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJkFQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4I7V.jpg)

Comment: Please add the codes as text, not as images/screenshots.

Comment: now can see codes

Comment: you should move that code from your adapter, it is wrong by SOLID principles. Use Delegate pattern to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You activity must implements `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` and implement the abstact methode `onTimeSet`:

```
    public class StudentList extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


 @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {

    }
}
```

and inside `onClick`

```
  DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance((((StudentList)view.getContext()),  persianCalendar.getPersianYear(),
                        persianCalendar.getPersianMonth(),
                        persianCalendar.getPersianDay());
```

OR :

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            }
        },  persianCalendar.getPersianYear(),
            persianCalendar.getPersianMonth(),
            persianCalendar.getPersianDay());
```

Comment: The way you said has no problem, but my first problem is that i can`t call StudentList Activity @B.M

Comment: Replace `StudentList.this` with  `((StudentList)view.getContext())`

Comment: The way you said has no problem but my date library just work with : DatePickerDialog.newInstance  @B.M

Comment: Wich library are you using ?

Comment: This way is right But i want to show date in a textview in AlertDialog in  RecyclerView now How can I communicate between them(StudentList)?

Comment: I must to make TextView known to the StudentList

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do now, show date in a textView in recyclerView in alertDialog, how is that ?

Comment: There's no way to put onTimeSet on the RecyclerView Adapter page instead of StudentList page ?

Comment: You can whether use  `OnDateSetListener ` or  `OnTimeSet` the same way

Comment: my problem has been resolved , with using : newInstance(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()) intsead of : newInstance((StudentList)view.getContext()) . You understand my problem well, I think you are a smart person , You helped me a lot. Thank you really @B.M

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the Activity's context when creating an instance of the adapter:

```
//Code in your Activity
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, ...);
```

Your adapter:

```
private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ...){
    this.context = context;
    //Rest of the constructor...
    }
```

By doing that, you could just add do this:

```
datePickerDialog.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePickerDialog");
```

Comment: I've done the way you said, but the problem has not been resolved @XabinCoffee

Answer (score 0):

You just need an activity context passed in your constructor. Be sure to call new Adapter(this,...) from activities and new Adapter(getActivity(),...) from fragments.

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

try this

Comment: The way you said has no problem, but my first problem is that i can`t call StudentList Activity @Android Geek

Comment: can u please share  the full code student list activity